# QT update Linedit at runtime

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to update the text on my linedit every time I get a frame, but my program crash. I tried doing the same with a loop, but the window shows only after the loop has finished. setH() is my slot, in Debug mode it run perfectly, the problem is when trying to update the text in LineEdit while the programm is running(the mainwindow is on the screen) . Thank you

```
void MainWindow::updatehand(){
    if (controller.isConnected()){
    int hc =frame.hands().count();
    QString hndc= QString::number(hc);
    emit hChanged(hndc);
}
void MainWindow::setH(const QString hndc){
    handsRead->setText(hndc);
    updatehand();
}
```

Comment: `MainWindow::handsRead` Static variable?

Comment: Do you connect the signal `hChanged()` with the slot `setH()`? When is the slot `setH()` triggered?

Comment: connect(this, SIGNAL(hChanged(const QString)),
this, SLOT(setH(const QString)));

Comment: @drescherjm: It is not static

Answer (score 1):

It is the reason for the crash:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(hChanged(const QString)), this, SLOT(setH(const QString)));
```

Such connection is acutally a direct function call. The function `setH()` is called in place of `emit hChanged(hndc);`. Then the function `updatehand()` is called from `setH()`.

It is an infinite loop with the stack overflow crash.

---

If you want to call `updatehand()` 60 times per seconds it is possible to called using `QTimer`, for example with `QTimer` statics memember:

```
void MainWindow::setH(const QString hndc){
    handsRead->setText(hndc);
    QTimer::singleShot(1000 / 60, this, SLOT(updatehand()));
}
```

Here `updatehand()` is also a slot.

In that case the even loop continues to dispatch UI messages after return from `setH()`.

Approximately after 16 ms the timer will call `updatehand()`.

---

The above solution technically breaks the infinite cross-refernce loop. However, it can be done better. There is a risk that `setH()` will be triggered many times from the external caller. In that case many timers will be activated.
It looks that you need just one `QTimer` instance to call periodiacally `updatehand()` independently of `setH()`. So, `updatehand()` can be pooled with given period to updated data. It can call `setH()` directly, the `setH()` function only sets the `QLineEdit` text:

```
void MainWindow::setH(const QString hndc){
    handsRead->setText(hndc);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried updating the Lineedit with a loop but the windows only show up when the loop has finished, is there a way to update the text on the lineedit of the mainwindow as I get it.

Comment: @David Do you really need such cross reference between those functions? I guess that there is also some external caller that triggers that loop calling either `hChanged()` or `setH()`.

Comment: How would you do it, I get a frame and get what I want from the frame and want to show that info in the LinEdit.

Comment: @David Please clarify your task. Why do you call `updatehand()` in `setH()`, what is the object `frame`?

Comment: To create a new frame and get the information from that frame. Does QT allow to modify LineEdit once that Mainwindow is shown?

Comment: @David How often those frames should be created? Immediately one by one or with some time interval?

Comment: Aproximately 60/s and every frame is in a different Thread, I am working with LeapMotion.

Comment: @David If you want new frames with some time interval the `QTimer` can be used, for example its static member `QTimer::singleShot(1000 / 60, this, SLOT(updatehand()));` instead of direct call from `setH`.

Comment: But how I update what i need to the lineedit, Signal does not do the job, As i say before the window is shown after the loop finish, once the mainwindow is shown no text can be added to LineEdit

Comment: @David I updated the answer. There is no direct loop with timer. The event loop dispatches messages while timer is activated.

Comment: Thank you so much I will try  right now and let you know.

Comment: Thank you it works, but i didn't get the info updated into LineEdit

Comment: @David What do you mean about updated info? If `handsRead` is the `QLineEdit` object the `setH()` must set it correctly. Maybe something wrong in `updatehand()`?

Comment: Yes you are correct handsRead is the LineEdit object, I tried running after the modification you subject, I use qDebug to see if what I need was updating correctly, and it is, but is not showing in QLineEdit. Thank You.

Comment: @David Are you sure that `frame` corresponds to the last frame? Do you need to call `controller.frame();` to get the last frame? By whe way, I see that it is possible to create a listener in LeapMotion that will automatically call your given function for each new frame. You shoudd be also careful with threads.

Comment: @David Do you mean that you see that `setH()` is called with correct updated value, but that value is not displayed after `handsRead->setText(hndc);`?

Comment: I Use Listener, before but had the same problem that I have now, the good think about using controller.frame() is that you get the frame when you need it.

Comment: Yes. this is the case.

Comment: @David If `handsRead->setText(hndc);` does not update UI while the UI thread is not blocked (window can be resized,...) it is very strange. You should debug it deeper and provide more information. For example, you can check in a new empty project that `lineedit->setText()` indeed updates the field and look for the differences with current project. You can even try in that test project that lineedit can be updated periodically by `QTimer`.

Comment: I was able to pull the text from the text() function of LineEdit but it did not show in the UI, however when I tried the setText() function with the timer the text was shown. It is possible that because the speed of which the frames were received caused the text not been displayed in the UI?

Comment: @David Does it work already with timer in your main project or it works only in empty test project?

Comment: @David That is good. So do you need more clarificaions for that question or the issue is resolved?

Comment: with the timer I was able to get the string I was supposed to show in the UI using the text() function but still don't show in the UI, I am starting from scratch using the timer as base. Thank you.

Comment: @David Glad to have been of help! You have an option to accept the answer if you feel it was useful to you http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work :-)